# batch remove quotes & comma from number in last occurrence of string

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with data

```
1,2,3,4,5,"100,6767.00"
1,2,3,4,5,"100,6767.00"
1,2,3,4,5,"100,6767.00"
```

my expected output

```
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
```

Unfortunately, I have windows & trying to make batch script

I know how to do it in Linux using awk & sed

how to do it in windows batch file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Using `substitution` combined with the numbers of `tokens` delimited by `,`:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%a in (Your_txt_file.txt) do (
  set "$line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f%%g"
  echo !$line:"=!
  )
  )>out.txt
```

Comment: `1,2,3,4,5,100,6767.00 ` is output of it. which is different than expected one

Comment: Didn't saw it check my EDIT !

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

(for /F tokens^=1^,2^ delims^=^" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%c in ("%%b") do echo %%a%%c%%d
)) > output.txt
```

Output example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
1,2,3,4,5,1006767.00
```